# Extracting point attributes to polygon grid in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector-grid, overlay

- *I have point data of endagered flowers found in a number of locations. Each location may have up to hundreds of flower
  registrations.*

  **I want to end up with a 1x1km grid colour graduated from the number of registration (not locations) in each grid cell.**

  I tried making a vector grid (that worked), but joining attriubutes
  by spatial overlap does not work. It runs, but table is blank.

  - Any idea of a different workflow or ideas on why i wont work?

Comment: Make sure the vector grid is a polygon grid, not lines or points. Make sure the grid is in the same CRS as the point layer.

Comment: What a rookie.... CRS was the problem... Thank you!